# How to compute projection rotate and graticule extend for d3.js satellite projection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am having hard time computing the right parameters for a demo of satellite projection.
In fact, I am trying to make a satellite projection of the geo location 34.0000° N, 9.0000° E. 
So, the rotate parameter for the d3.geo.satellite() would be :

```
rotate([10, 34, ?])
```

But I don't know how to define the roll. Also, could you please explain how to define graticule parameters.

Here's what I did till now, but the graph is not showing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.graticule {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #777;
}

.boundary {
  fill: #ccc;
  fill-opacity: .8;
  stroke: #000;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.geo.projection.v0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>
//satellite projection of tunisia 
//


var width = 1200,
    height = 960;

//what is a projection is general ? 
var projection = d3.geo.satellite()
    .distance(1.1)
    .scale(2500)
    // what does rotate do? 
    //If rotation is specified, sets the projection’s three-axis rotation to the specified longitude, latitude and roll in degrees and returns the projection
    .rotate([50, -20, 20])//rotate([36, 10, 32]) //([76.00, -34.50, 32.12])
    //center: changes the center of the overall globe 
    .center([-3, 6])
    //what tilt does?  after few tests, I still don't know ...
    .tilt(28)
    .clipAngle(Math.acos(1 / 1.1) * 180 / Math.PI - 1e-6) //doesn't change 
    .precision(.1);


//what is a graticule? 
//      a network of lines representing meridians and parallels, on which a map or plan can be represented.
var graticule = d3.geo.graticule()
    // how to compute the major and minor extent for graticule ? 
    .extent([[-60, 15], [-50 + 1e-6, 200 + 1e-6]])
    //step will define the dimensions of the rectangles within the map graticule 
    .step([2, 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("path")
    .datum(graticule)
    .attr("class", "graticule")
    .attr("d", path);

d3.json("data/tunisia.json", function(error, topology) {
  console.log(topology);


  svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.governorates))
      .attr("class", "boundary")
      .attr("d", path);
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you got it right - the only thing is that you have to make the numbers *negative* because of the direction of the rotation.

So `rotate([-10, -34, 0])` would have got you most of the way there. The roll parameter is very obvious when you play with it - it just rotates the view point of the current location of globe in one direction or another on the axis that is pointing perpendicularly out.

Also note that the graticule lines, without an extent specified, cover the globe. However, you can use extents just to draw a layer of graticule lines just around the geographic region of interest. Again, I recommend experimenting by changing values and seeing how d3 reacts!

Example below (borrowing the JSON from your gist). If you want to experiment with the values, I also recommend using something like [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yKl8LYQB3OYDjKW1YtzN?p=preview) which will redraw the projection each time you make a change to a value. I used `rotate([-15, -31, -20])` to add a different perspective:

```js
var width = 800,
    height = 600;

//what is a projection is general ? 
var projection = d3.geo.satellite()
    .distance(1.1)
    .scale(5500)
    // what does rotate do? 
    //If rotation is specified, sets the projection’s three-axis rotation to the specified longitude, latitude and roll in degrees and returns the projection
    .rotate([-15, -31, -20])
    //.rotate([36, 10, 32]) 
    //.rotate([76.00, -34.50, 32.12])
    //center: changes the center of the overall globe 
    .center([-1, 5])
    //what tilt does?  after few tests, I still don't know ...
    .tilt(10)
    .clipAngle(Math.acos(1 / 1.1) * 180 / Math.PI - 1e-6) //doesn't change 
    .precision(.1);


//what is a graticule? 
//      a network of lines representing meridians and parallels, on which a map or plan can be represented.
var graticule = d3.geo.graticule()
    // how to compute the major and minor extent for graticule ? 
    .extent([[-10, -40], [40 + 1e-6, 100 + 1e-6]])
    //step will define the dimensions of the rectangles within the map graticule 
    .step([2, 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("path")
    .datum(graticule)
    .attr("class", "graticule")
    .attr("d", path);

d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mohamed-ali/8732826/raw/06ef0c05110f9c1ed5f911399e9bc9283b640cf1/tunisia.json", function(error, topology) {
  console.log(topology);
  console.log(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.governorates));

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.governorates))
      .attr("class", "boundary")
      .attr("d", path);

});
```

```css
.graticule {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #777;
}

.boundary {
  fill: #ccc;
  fill-opacity: .8;
  stroke: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.geo.projection.v0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<h1>Test D3 Geo Projection</div>
```